# How do I prevent Twig from encoding HTML?

Tags: templating, plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I've created a field type that stores its value as a model. That model’s `__toString()` method returns the result of a `craft()->templates->render()` call:

```php
public function render() 
{
    $render = craft()->templates->render('myplugin/templates/mymodeltemplate');
    return $render;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->render();
}
```

When I output the model from a template, like so:

```twig
{{ entry.myField }}
```

Twig encodes the resulting HTML as a string with HTML entities.  Running the string through `html_entity_decode()` before returning it in `__toString()` doesn't help.  I'm assuming this string formatting is happening somewhere at the Twig level.

Being new to Craft, I'd love to understand a little more of what's going on here.  How does the string representation of an element model get passed to and handled by Twig?

Comment: Hey Angela, I’ve edited your question to focus on the first issue it was bringing up. Try to stick to that single-question format going forward. So your routing question should be its own separate question, for example.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me organize & navigate this, Brandon!

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you output anything with Twig’s `{{ output tags }}`, the contents will get encoded by default. You have to pass the content through the [`|raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter in order for it to be output verbatim.

```twig
{{ entry.myFieldHandle|raw }}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon Kelly.  Passing the content through `|raw` works, but I'd like this work to be handled by my pugin on the backend.  When I try returning `TemplateHelper::getRaw($html)` in my `__toString()` function, I get an Internal Server Error:  `__toString()` must return a string.

Comment: Doh! Guess you’ll have to stick with `|raw` :-/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public function getFunctions() {
    return array (
        'my_func' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('my_func', array($this, 'my_func'), array('is_safe' => array('html')))
    );
}
```

This being the important part:

```
array('is_safe' => array('html'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about model, but you can return raw, unescaped value from plugin variable like this:

```
use craft\helpers\Template as TemplateHelper;

class someClass
{
    public function someFunction()
    {
        return TemplateHelper::raw($some_values);
    }
}
```